# Error calling CreateEnvelope : TAB_PAGE_NUMBER_NOT_SPECIFIED

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docusignapi, digital-signature, docusigncompositetmplts

I am a beginner in **DocuSign API** programming. I have a `.cshtml` page for create envelope for sending to customer. When I try to create envelop from DocuSign API it shows error message like:

> Page number not specified in tab element. Page Number or AnchorTabItem missing for tab \"SignHere\"."

Please see my HTML and code below.

Html

```
 <span>
         <br />
           <br />
<span><b>SIGNATURE:</b></span> <span style="color:white;">pleasesignhereBP</span>
                <br />
                <br />
      <span><b>DATE:</b></span><span style="color:white;">pleasedatehereBP</span>
                <br />
                <br />
            </span>
```

Code

```
SignerModel objPerson = new SignerModel();

            TabsModel objPersonTab = new TabsModel();
            List<SignHereModel> lstPersonSignHere = new List<SignHereModel>();
            SignHereModel objPersonSignHere = new SignHereModel();
            objPersonSignHere.DocumentId = "1";
            objPersonSignHere.PageNumber = "1";
            objPersonSignHere.RecipientId = "2";
            objPersonSignHere.AnchorString = "pleasesignhereBP";
            objPersonSignHere.AnchorXOffset = ".2";
            objPersonSignHere.AnchorYOffset = ".01";
            objPersonSignHere.AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "true";
            objPersonSignHere.AnchorUnits = "cms";
            lstPersonSignHere.Add(objPersonSignHere);
            objPersonTab.SignHereTabs = lstPersonSignHere;

            List<DateModel> lstPersonDateHere = new List<DateModel>();
            DateModel objPersonDate = new DateModel();
            objPersonDate.DocumentId = "1";
            objPersonDate.PageNumber = "1";
            objPersonDate.RecipientId = "1";
            objPersonDate.AnchorString = "pleasedatehereBP";
            objPersonDate.AnchorXOffset = ".2";
            objPersonDate.AnchorYOffset = ".01";
            objPersonDate.AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "true";
            objPersonDate.AnchorUnits = "cms";
            objPersonDate.Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            lstPersonDateHere.Add(objPersonDate);
            objPersonTab.DateTabs = lstPersonDateHere;

            objPerson.Tabs = objPersonTab;
```

I already added the  **objPersonDate.PageNumber = "1"** but it's not working.

### Updates

I have DocuSign.eSign library in my project solution. I refer this project my webapplication. Then i do some changes in the `SetDocuSignSigners` *function* of `DocuSignCommunicator` class.

```
objSHere.PageNumber = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objSHere.PageNumber)) ? objSHere.PageNumber : "1";
```

Please see my detailed code below.

```
    private List<Signer> SetDocuSignSigners(List<SignerModel> lstSignerModel)
    {
        List<Signer> lstSigner = new List<Signer>();
        if (lstSignerModel != null && lstSignerModel.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (SignerModel objModel in lstSignerModel)
            {
                Signer objSigner = new Signer();
                objSigner.Name = objModel.Name;
                objSigner.Email = objModel.Email;
                objSigner.RecipientId = objModel.RecipientId;
                objSigner.RoutingOrder = objModel.RoutingOrder;
                Tabs objTab = new Tabs();
                List<SignHere> lstSalesSignHere = new List<SignHere>();
                List<DateSigned> lstSalesDateHere = new List<DateSigned>();
                List<FullName> lstSalesNameHere = new List<FullName>();

                if (objModel.Tabs != null)
                {
                    if (objModel.Tabs.SignHereTabs != null && objModel.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (SignHereModel objSignHere in objModel.Tabs.SignHereTabs)
                        {
                            SignHere objSHere = new Model.SignHere();
                            objSHere.PageNumber = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objSHere.PageNumber)) ? objSHere.PageNumber : "1";
                            objSHere.AnchorString = objSignHere.AnchorString;
                            objSHere.DocumentId = objSignHere.DocumentId;
                            objSHere.RecipientId = objSignHere.RecipientId;
                            objSHere.AnchorXOffset = objSignHere.AnchorXOffset;
                            objSHere.AnchorYOffset = objSignHere.AnchorYOffset;
                            objSHere.AnchorUnits = objSignHere.AnchorUnits;
                            objSHere.AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = objSignHere.AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent;
                            objSHere.AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true";
                            lstSalesSignHere.Add(objSHere);
                        }
                    }

                    if (objModel.Tabs.DateTabs != null && objModel.Tabs.DateTabs.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (DateModel objDateHere in objModel.Tabs.DateTabs)
                        {
                            DateSigned objDSHere = new DateSigned();
                            objDSHere.PageNumber = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objDSHere.PageNumber)) ? objDSHere.PageNumber : "1"; 
                            objDSHere.AnchorString = objDateHere.AnchorString;
                            objDSHere.DocumentId = objDateHere.DocumentId;
                            objDSHere.RecipientId = objDateHere.RecipientId;
                            objDSHere.AnchorXOffset = objDateHere.AnchorXOffset;
                            objDSHere.AnchorYOffset = objDateHere.AnchorYOffset;
                            objDSHere.AnchorUnits = objDateHere.AnchorUnits;
                            objDSHere.AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = objDateHere.AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent;
                            objDSHere.AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true";
                            ////objDSHere.Value = objDateHere.Value;
                            lstSalesDateHere.Add(objDSHere);
                        }
                    }

                    if (objModel.Tabs.FullNameTabs != null && objModel.Tabs.FullNameTabs.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (FullNameModel objDateHere in objModel.Tabs.FullNameTabs)
                        {
                            FullName objNameHere = new FullName();
                            objNameHere.PageNumber = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objNameHere.PageNumber)) ? objNameHere.PageNumber : "1"; 
                            objNameHere.AnchorString = objDateHere.AnchorString;
                            objNameHere.DocumentId = objDateHere.DocumentId;
                            objNameHere.RecipientId = objDateHere.RecipientId;
                            objNameHere.AnchorXOffset = objDateHere.AnchorXOffset;
                            objNameHere.AnchorYOffset = objDateHere.AnchorYOffset;
                            objNameHere.AnchorUnits = objDateHere.AnchorUnits;
                            objNameHere.AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = objDateHere.AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent;
                            objNameHere.Value = objDateHere.Value;
                            objNameHere.AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true";
                            lstSalesNameHere.Add(objNameHere);
                        }
                    }
                }

                objTab.SignHereTabs = lstSalesSignHere;
                objTab.DateSignedTabs = lstSalesDateHere;
                objTab.FullNameTabs = lstSalesNameHere;
                objSigner.Tabs = objTab;
                lstSigner.Add(objSigner);
            }
        }

        return lstSigner;
    }
```

I don't know this is a best practice but my issue is solved. Please advice if this is not a good practice.

**After the library change**

Sadly it's not working in the signature placement in documents. I have two fields in my document *Signature* and *Signaturedate* but these fields are placed in wrong placement when I signed the document via DocuSign website. Please see the document below.

[image]

So assign page number is not a solution for my issue.

Comment: Can you capture exact JSON request posted to DocuSign? You can capture exact JSON by following steps explained [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging)

Comment: +Amit K Bist, good call, added to answer, hopefull +Ragesh S will be able to report back and update us!

Comment: @Amit K Bist Thank you very much for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update above with actual code change, because with what you are showing and what you "Say" below it seems in conflict.

It looks like you are missing the "TabId" aka "Tab Item"

```
              "name": "sample string 1",
              "tabLabel": "sample string 2",
              "scaleValue": 3.1,
              "optional": "sample string 4",
              "documentId": "sample string 5",
              "recipientId": "sample string 6",
              "pageNumber": "sample string 7",
              "xPosition": "sample string 8",
              "yPosition": "sample string 9",
              "anchorString": "sample string 10",
              "anchorXOffset": "sample string 11",
              "anchorYOffset": "sample string 12",
              "anchorUnits": "sample string 13",
              "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "sample string 14",
              "tabId": "sample string 15",
              "conditionalParentLabel": "sample string 16",
              "conditionalParentValue": "sample string 17"
```

https://www.docusign.net/restapi/help

I really suggest using PostMan Client and / or SoapUI to validate you can make your api call, especially in the beginning. This way you can see the actual error returned, as it will say more about the error in the response for very common mistakes. PostMan or SoapUI will issue the actual API calls successfully (Demo or Prod once you have passed prod API certification) showing you the actual response without having to worry about coding typo's, properties of objects or debugging logging to see what really came back.

This allows you to learn the DocuSign API while using your choice of SDK. You did the right thing asking for help here on Stack Overflow.

I have a couple links for you to get started:

DocuSign Developer Center where you probably found the PHP SDK https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/sdk-tools

Link for info on PostMan (older version, you can get the latest one - aka Orange Rocket Man logo vs blue world, for Chrome or Mac Standalone - https://blog.grigsbyconsultingllc.com/postman-rest-client-a-google-chrome-app/

X-DocuSign-Authentication Header Q&A on StackOverflow How should the header X-DocuSign-Authentication be used for REST and SOAP?

I like the concept of the DocuSign API explorer to start with, sad part is it doesn't work against prod, so you still have to use something else when you move from demo to prod.

And as mention above by "Amit K Bist" you can you capture exact JSON request posted your PHP | API calls by following steps explained at this DocuSign support article https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging

Best of Luck and Enjoy your DocuSign API journey!

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable and detailed reply.

Comment: @RageshS Thank you and you are welcome. Thanks for updating us!

May I make a suggestion for the sake of others using StackOverflow to find specific solutions?

Let's break your project into the separate issues.  Aka, first was the "Tab error" which was this question. So let's mark this question answered (only you can do this) and that the "TabItem id" was probably the issue.

Comment: @RageshS (con't) 

Then post a new question about "Fixed vs Anchor" locations and then I or others can jump in and help you with that. I suspect the PDF is an image only, with no "text or white text added by you" to allow the anchor to be found, and since you said okay if not found to still place, it put them at the top (default action when location x,y not specified or anchor text missing.