# what is the proper class for an MVC DocuSign WebHook receiver in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docusignapi, digital-signature, signature

I am a beginner in DocuSign API Implementation. I have a `webhook` type action in my controller, thate inherited from `ApiController` base class.

```
 public class DocuSignController : ApiController
```

But it's always shows a message like below.

> The controller for path '/XXX/XXX' was not found or
>   does not implement IController.

I know this issue the `ApiController` not inherited from the `IController` class. But the webhook needed `ApiController` (I hope i am right).

My website have already SSL enabled (this is required), already published this code into server.

Is any additional configuration needed for this?

Comment: Looks like you need to inherit your controller from MVC controller class, not APIController class.

Comment: But DocuSign needed ApiController

Comment: @RageshS Hey I think ChetanR has a valid point and to help you with that, take a look at https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2017/03/11/integrate-docusign-with-a-c-mvc-website/ and the project code at https://github.com/jeremylindsayni/Magellanic.DigitalSignature/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=controller&type=

You will see the "controller" class vs ApiController. Please let us know what you determine. Then we can work on updating your question to the real question (more of what is the proper class for an MVC DocuSign WebHook receiver) and get an answer documented :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper class for an MVC DocuSign WebHook receiver in C# is `Controller`.

```
namespace DocuSignWebSample.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
```

Sample Code at https://github.com/jeremylindsayni/Magellanic.DigitalSignature

Overview Blog article at https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2017/03/11/integrate-docusign-with-a-c-mvc-website/

Reminder, when using other's code, understand your company's licensing related code policy's.

Comment: You mean it doesn't need inherit from ApiController.

Comment: @RageshS that was ChetanR and my conclusion. Based on what I can find out there and my past experience it matches. Also, if you search the sample GIT Repro, you will NOT find ApiController, only "controller" which matches your error message complaining about needing IController.